# TS infer from return type of callback property of an object parameter

Tags: typescript

I have this issue trying to infer type for function `post` return type. It's second parameter is an object that has a `transform` property. So if `transform` parameter is provided then `post`'s return type should be `transform`'s return type, else the first the first generic type provided for `post` function. I hope to be understood.

```
type DefautlHttpCallInit = {  
  throttle?: number;
  baseUrl?: string;
  url?: string;
  onSend?(e: HttpCallInit) : void | Promise<void>;
}

export type HttpCallInit = RequestInit & DefautlHttpCallInit 

export type HttpCallInitOf<T> = RequestInit & DefautlHttpCallInit & {
  transform?: <TOut>(v: T) => TOut
};

export type HttpCallerInstance = {  
  post<T, TInit extends HttpCallInitOf<T>>(data?: T, init?: TInit): Promise<TInit extends {transform(e: T): infer XOut} ? XOut : T>;
  
}

//hack reference
let r = {} as HttpCallerInstance;

interface Post {
    id?: number;
    title: string;
}

interface User {
  id: number;
  userName: string;
}

interface UserPost extends Post{
  user: User
}

const user = {/* info props */} as User;

r.post({title: 'New post'} as Post, {
  //First: infer 
  transform(post) { 
    return Object.assign(post, {user}) as UserPost
  }
})
```

**Compiler Options**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "Latest",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

[**Typescript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBDArsANgCWMMBhRaaAkgHYCWwUAvFAN5RQBQDwAFgE4D22aEA-AC4oJZAFsARhHYBuZlHGIAzhACq7NIKiLg7MiQDmshsnWbtug0aicSAZQgkAJnwAUEIVhz5CpCgEooIQA3TjJHKAAfKAAFLlEyZQAeELCAPlkAX0ZGCAAPME52SlBIKE88AmJyShoAJQgAR2QIbV9KADJYBBR0cu8qiiYc-MLi8Gg+yraAeXhEgBVU6ih6ppbgNqhOuCRUTGwKn2qtujkdRBJFeELRTQXp1FSXIKF5gKol+YfgRgzZYYKRSgJQmB36UlI2guAGNoDR6EwGAVtAsADRQeabPLAByORRlMFTaqzBapJ6ORDARCaebovQUGltPxCWKceJJTHHbG4-G0c6Xa7sURuV7MqB6eBSKAADW+GSgfBl30CGPScl+2V4lHYy1o8qUBK8lQhlypJFh-z0OPYSFhMU42lODAYYU0IgkUisLAovCE5j0hg1jCtUlt0BUyh1tDkYSE7skMjkyEjADlEKJ3FodAHMtkQzbEHaI1Jog7KNynPjS9po8ZI0Ji+wg9CbI7k1L4QB6ABU4pI1ygYC4YHx3c7+vxjf+7AAdMjgC4+T7MwByFMQADug7LK4n9u06NrUE7nYAYmR2NohBKpWd2BcrjcXPOAvQ5Ax2BBgCYSFBpuIACsIGhYAZyURQyH0EhnzLQ923YDIAgNRtqx+BgskQoA)

And I have this error log:
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are specifying the generic `TOut` as a generic on the transform itself but that is not what it represents, a generic on a method or function dictates behaviour when it gets called.  You want to specify the transform output type at declaration (in the same place as `T`) then specify it as a generic of the `post` function [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBDArsANgCWMMBhRaaAkgHYCWwUAvFAN5RQBQDwAFgE4D22aEA-AC4oJZAFsARhHYBuZlHGIAzhACq7NIKiLg7MiQDmshsnWbtug0aicSAZQgkAJnwAUEIVhz5CpCgEooIQA3TjJHKAAfKAAFLlEyZQAeELCAPlkAX0ZGCAAPME52SlBIKE88AmJyShoAJQgAR2QIbV9KADJYBBR0cu8qiiYc-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-WDfxMM8iynYA5RHVECPjXJDnYAA6SlgBcQliIcYAyOWGcGC1AAxMh2G0IQ9G9St-l1cVRBcJiAnoOQGDPYATBIKBpnEAArI9gHopRFDIfQSGkkcuIw9gMj8OQsnM7JqMoEA5TiBIIESBcyJuGhcmkKBlyxIMUL-UQwA5MhxF4W1hGtKQuEE+igA):

```js
export type HttpCallInitOf<T, TransformedType = T> = RequestInit & DefautlHttpCallInit & {
  transform?: (v: T) => TransformedType
};

export type HttpCallerInstance = {  
  post<T, TransformedType = T>(data?: T, init?: HttpCallInitOf<T,TransformedType>): Promise<TransformedType>;
  // TransformedType is defaults to T so if it can't be infered it stays as T
}
```

Comment: Just great! Thanks!

Comment: Whould be posible to make `transform` return-type not dependant of `T`?

Comment: are you running into a case where `=T` is not working properly and `TransformedType` is something like` unknown`? Code example would help

Comment: Never mind, I see it works fine, I was just doing it wrong